# OOP GUI Error: main.lua:4: attempt to index local (a boolean value)... Issue with modules

Tags: oop, module, lua, love2d

Today, I was messing around with trying to make a gui class for game I'd like to start making in LOVE2D. I decided to try and use OOP to make creating new menus easier in the future. The OOP works great until I try and put it into it's own module, where it gives me the error above. I've double and triple checked my code against similar code and I can't find the problem. I've also looked it up and there are similar threads, but nothing that helps my problem. Here is the relevant code...

From the main.lua

```
local gui = {
x = 0, y = 0, 
width = 0, height = 0, 

popupSpeed = 300,

active = false,

color = {red = 0, blue = 0, green = 0, alpha = 0},

menuType = "",

--buttons = require "Game/buttons"
}
```

And from the gui.lua...

```
local newGUI = require "Game/gui"

local menus = { 
    playerInv = newGUI.new()
}
function love.load()
    menus.playerInv:createDropDown("right" , _, 30, 100, love.graphics.getHeight() - 60, 50, 128, 50, 255)
end

function gui.new() 
    newMenu = {}
    for k, v in pairs(gui) do
        newMenu[k] = v
    end
    return newMenu
end

function gui:createDropDown(direction, x, y, width, height, red, blue, green, alpha)
    self.red = red
    self.blue = blue
    self.green = green
    self.alpha = alpha
    if direction == "right" then 
        self.x = love.graphics.getWidth() - width
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.menuType = "rightDropDown"
    elseif direction == "left" then
        self.x = 0
        self.y = y
        self.widthMax = width
        self.height = height
        self.menuType = "leftDropDown"
    elseif direction == "down" then
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.heightMax = height
        self.menuType = "regDropDown"
    end
end

function gui:drawGui()
    if self.active == true then
        love.graphics.setColor(self.red, self.blue, self.green, self.alpha)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 10, 10, 6) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the first snippet is Game/gui and that the second part is main.lua, if this is so, You are attempting to call `.new()` function which is clearly absent on your Game/gui file. You need to move all of gui's functions to it's own file as well, this includes `gui.new()`, `gui:createDropDown` and `gui:drawGui()` last but not least, you have to return gui at the end of it's own file.

Your main file should end up somewhat like this:

```
local newGUI = require "Game/gui"

local menus = { 
    playerInv = newGUI.new()
}
function love.load()
    menus.playerInv:createDropDown("right" , _, 30, 100, love.graphics.getHeight() - 60, 50, 128, 50, 255)
end
```

and Game/gui somewhat like this:

```
local gui = {} -- With all the stuff inside

function gui.new() 
-- With all the stuff it had inside
end

function gui:createDropDown()
-- With all the stuff it had inside
end

function gui:drawGui()
-- With all the stuff it had inside
end

return gui
```

You see, you forgot to move its functions to its own file, and return gui itself. Don't forget to replace what i omitted on Game/gui!

Comment: Thanks!  I figured that out a little bit before I read this, but this still helps. Also, is there a good tutorial or thread or something like that about how to build a gui in lua?

Comment: Love2D should have some good sample projects, reading, running and modifying example code is a great way to learn. https://love2d.org/wiki/examples.love